# How to Use UnCSS with NPM Scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, uncss

Right now I am able to search a single html file using a custom script using NPM scripts.  In particular, the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "uncss": "uncss index.html > ./lib/css/app.css"
  }
```

What I can't figure out is how to create a script which will search all of the html files in my project (without searching the node_modules folder).

Any ideas?